# Delete all images in pub/media/catalog/product not linked to any product

Tags: database, product-images, media-images

I am facing a website wich media directory size is **88 GB**, and that is getting problems with the server and some processes. After analyzing the product date, I determined that in this directory exists so many images that are not assigned to any product in the database. Is there any way to get all those images not linked to a product and delete them?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Hackathon EAV cleaner module for remove unused images. After installation you can use the command `eav:media:remove-unused`

this is a module https://github.com/magento-hackathon/EAVCleaner/tree/magento2

Answer (score 0):

use Magento Store Manager free trial,it has store diagnostics that finds that images and allows to delete them